# Relationship btw. surface areas of a cone within a cylinder

Tags: geometry, optimization, surfaces

let say we have a cone within a cylinder
[image]

The volumes of cylinder and cone are related by 
$$
\frac{V_{cone}}{V_{cylinder}} = \frac{1}{3} 
$$

We have also following formulas for surface areas:
$$
A_{cylinder} = 2\pi r(r+h) \\
A_{cone} = \pi r(r+ \sqrt{r^2 + h^2})
$$

with $r$ and $h$ being the radius and height.

**Quastions**:

1. I am actually intrested if there is any simple relationship betwenn these sourfaces, like this:
   $$
   A_{cone} = \lambda  A_{cylinder}
   $$
2. Also is following correct:
   If there are some $(r_0, h_0)$ which minimize the area of the cylinder, they will respectively minimize the area of the cone?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You already know the formulas for the two areas. By dividing them you see that the ratio is $$\frac{A_{\text{cone}}}{A_{\text{cylinder}}} = \frac{r+\sqrt{r^2+h^2}}{2(r+h)}$$There is no slick reduction that will somehow make that a constant. Just plugging in a few values of $r$ and $h$ will show you that it varies with respect to each.
2. Technically this is correct, but only because the value of $r$ that minimizes $A_{\text{cylinder}}$ is $r = 0$ (and any $h$), which makes the area $0$, and of course it also makes $A_{\text{cone}} = 0$. I am sure that is not what you are after.

Perhaps you meant to minimize the area with respect to some condition?

Comment: To 1) i did it actually already but i could not come up with a constant factor. so i thought there will be maybe some mathematical "trick" - e.g. some kind of transformation, wich could relate both surfaces as a factor. To 2) I am actually intrested in a proof of this concept. And yes the conditions given are: {r>= 0, h>=0, V_cone=v_0}. thanks

Comment: Proof: The areas are $\ge 0$ so $0$ is the minimum value. $r =0$ makes both areas $0$ QED.